# Is there any Spark or Giraph implement of Louvain method?

Tags: apache-spark, giraph

This is louvain method to find community in social graph.

https://sites.google.com/site/findcommunities/

I want to run it on a big graph using BSP method such as Spark or Giraph.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Sotera/spark-distributed-louvain-modularity/tree/master/dga-graphx

maybe this what you need,i am just testing this code,it run on spark